# Can I store all arguments of callback function into an array in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to know does there exists any way to store all arguments of callback function into an array ?  and can I know the numbers of arguments of callback function should I catch ?

for example

some callback function will receive 2 arguments err and rows. Can I store them into an array?

```
c.query('SHOW DATABASES', function(err, rows) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  console.dir(rows);
});
```

thanks

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking. Can you provide some example pseudocode of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the arguments with which the function is invoked, with the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object
of the function. 
The arguments objects is an array like object (but not exactly array). To get an array of your arguments you can use

`var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

The [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property specifies the number of arguments expected by the function

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  console.log(arguments.length);
  console.log(args);
}

foo(1,2,3,'a',true);
```